# Slow group by execution after update to MySQL 8.0.26

Tags: mysql, update, group-by

I am running a larger DB with tables > 200M datasets on a dedicated Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

Since a few days queries that use group by are extremly slow. I suspect that this is new since the last apt-get update of Ubuntu which might have updated MySql from 8.0.25 to 8.0.26 but I am not sure.

Current Version: mysql  Ver 8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

Here is a sample query:

```
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE) as time_sec,
  m.name AS POS,
  AVG(RATING)
FROM   merchants_product_ratings mpr
INNER JOIN merchants m ON mpr.merchant_id = m.id
INNER JOIN manufacturers_products p ON mpr.SKU = p.SKU
LEFT JOIN manufacturers_brands b ON p.brand_id = b.ID
WHERE
    MERCHANT_ID IN ( '1','2','4' )
  AND p.MANUFACTURER_ID = 19130
  AND FIND_IN_SET(b.ID_PARENT, '14255,113,124')
  AND CASE WHEN 0 = 1 THEN p.focus=1 ELSE TRUE END -- show only focus PZNs? 
  AND DATE BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1625335554) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1630519554)
GROUP BY DATE, mpr.MERCHANT_ID
ORDER BY 
    date, m.name
```

The query is unmodified and worked before in <1s

SQL Mode: `sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,IGNORE_SPACE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

Now I am wondering how to fix it as it was previsously running and if it is a result of a wrong SQL mode or wrong group by. There are several other examples of the same type where it also comes down to the fact that a query on each merchant alone runs < 100ms but once there are more to group by it slows down to > 30s.`

From MySQL status on used RAM:

```
InnoDB Buffer Pool Data 40 GiB
Key Buffer Size 16 MiB
InnoDB Log Buffer Size 16 MiB
```

Total RAM 128G
Buffer Pool Size: 104G

Answer (score 0):

`FIND_IN_SET(mpr.MERCHANT_ID, '1,2,4')` is not sargable.  Change to
`mpr.MERCHANT_ID IN (1,2,4)`.  Ditto for the other `FIND_in_set`.

`MERCHANT_ID IN ( '1','2','4' )` is the same as above.  The redundancy may be harmful to performance.

What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM do you have?  What does `SHOW TABLE STATUS` say for the relevant tables?  I am concerned that the tables recently grew in size, leading to being I/O-bound instead of running in cache.

Also, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables.  A common mistake is not to index many:many tables (like `manufacturers_products`) in the optimal way.  Another possibility relates to 'composite' indexes.